# How to merge arrays by value and type

Tags: php

I have the following arrays :

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( 
        [id] => 1 
        [name] => Apple
        [type] => Fruit 
    ) 
    [1] => Array ( 
        [id] => 3 
        [name] => Chanterelles
        [type] => Vegetable
    ) 
    [2] => Array ( 
        [id] => 4 
        [name] => Lenses
        [type] => Legume
    ) 
    [3] => Array ( 
        [id] => 2 
        [name] => Banana
        [type] => Fruit
    ) 
    [4] => Array ( 
        [id] => 5 
        [name] => Rocket
        [type] => Vegetable
    ) 
)
```

My expected ouput :

```
Array (
    [Fruit] => Array (
        Array (
            [id] => 1 
            [name] => Apple
        )
        Array (
            [id] => 2
            [name] => Banana
        )
    )
    [Vegetable] => Array (
        Array (
            [id] => 3
            [name] => Chanterelles
        )
        Array (
            [id] => 5
            [name] => Rocket
        )
    )
    [Legume] => Array (
        Array (
            [id] => 4
            [name] => Lenses
        )
    )
)
```

My initial array :

```
var_dump(array(
    array(
        'id' => 1,
        'name' => 'Apple',
        'type' => 'Fruit'
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 3,
        'name' => 'Chanterelles',
        'type' => 'Vegetable'
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 4,
        'name' => 'Lenses',
        'type' => 'Legume'
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 2,
        'name' => 'Banana',
        'type' => 'Fruit'
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 5,
        'name' => 'Rocket',
        'type' => 'Vegetable'
    )
));
```

I tried the following :

```
foreach($myarray as $ingredient){
    $type_arr[] = $ingredient['type'];
}
$type_arr_uq = array_unique($type_arr);
$new_arr = array();
foreach($type_arr_uq as $type){
  foreach($myarray as $ingredient){
      if($type == $ingredient['type']){
          $new_arr[$type] = ['id' => $ingredient['id'], 'name' => $ingredient['name']];
      }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [Fruit] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [name] => Banana
        )

    [Vegetable] => Array
        (
            [id] => 5
            [name] => Rocket
        )

    [Legume] => Array
        (
            [id] => 4
            [name] => Lenses
        )

)
```

Demo: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/4886faa73b56b62fdf954f06e902f1d0bd301a71

Answer (score 2):

```
$new_arr[$type] = ['id' => $ingredient['id'], 'name' => $ingredient['name']];
```

You are overwriting the potentially already existing array entry in this place - add a new one instead:

```
$new_arr[$type][] = ['id' => $ingredient['id'], 'name' => $ingredient['name']];
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this approach?

```
<?php


function groupArray($array, $key) {
    $return = array();
    foreach($array as $val) {
        $return[$val[$key]][] = $val;
    }
    return $return;
}

$myArray = array(
    array(
        'id' => 1,
        'name' => 'Apple',
        'type' => 'Fruit'
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 3,
        'name' => 'Chanterelles',
        'type' => 'Vegetable'
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 4,
        'name' => 'Lenses',
        'type' => 'Legume'
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 2,
        'name' => 'Banana',
        'type' => 'Fruit'
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 5,
        'name' => 'Rocket',
        'type' => 'Vegetable'
    )
);

print_r(groupArray($myArray, 'type'));

?>
```

the output is :

```
Array ( [Fruit] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 1 [name] => Apple [type] => Fruit ) [1] => Array ( [id] => 2 [name] => Banana [type] => Fruit ) ) [Vegetable] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 3 [name] => Chanterelles [type] => Vegetable ) [1] => Array ( [id] => 5 [name] => Rocket [type] => Vegetable ) ) [Legume] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 4 [name] => Lenses [type] => Legume ) ) )
```

Answer (score 0):

I can to advice [array_reduce](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php) function:

```
$groupped_array = array_reduce(
    $myarray,
    function($carry, $item) {
        if (!isset($carry[$item['type']])) $carry[$item['type']] = [];
        array_push($carry[$item['type']], [$item['id'], $item['name']]);
        return $carry;
    },
    []
);
```

Test in [PHP sandbox](https://phpize.online/?phpses=22908dd9987623a2eca3dbad49c1689f&sqlses=null&php_version=php5&sql_version=mysql57)

Answer (score 0):

Very simple example:

```
$result = [];
    foreach ($array as $value) {
        $type = $value['type'];
        unset($value['type']);
        $result[$type][] = $value;
    }
```